# Do I need to keep .watchmanconfig file in react-native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, watchman

default react native project generates `.watchmanconfig` file that is simply empty object `{}`, can I safely delete this?

A subquestion would be: is there any watchman configuration I can do / refference to improve react-native project experience somehow?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`.watchmanconfig` can be safely deleted.

If `Watchman` does not find the `.watchmanconfig` relative to your `root` directory, then it will simply load the `watchman configuration` present in `/etc/watchman.json` in your global configuration.

You don't need to provide a Watchman Configuration unless your `project files` become very large as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/463#issuecomment-301321432)

Hope it helps!