# .watchmanconfig file missing from react native app

Tags: reactjs, macos, react-native, watchman

I'm building my first React Native app. I tried 3 different ways of creating a new project:
*npx react-native init, create-react-native-app, expo init*.

I have installed, Homebrew, Expo, Watchman, Create React Native App.

No matter which way I try creating a new React Native project, the `.watchmanconfig` file is missing. I've read other forums stating to simply add the `.watchmanconfig` file and add `{}`.

But does this really solve the problem? Is it possible I did not install watchman correctly?

I have also gone into my security settings (MAC) and gave full disk access to watchman.

I've gone to the Watchman site and tried reading the docs to understand if I missing something somewhere but it's a little confusing.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe your watchman is not installed correctly somehow when you create a different project it will create a different watchman file and use that but if it did not present then it uses the root file which I think causing a problem for you. Maybe this can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297764/do-i-need-to-keep-watchmanconfig-file-in-react-native-project

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar I clicked on the link and read through but none of those additional links are providing a solution as to how/where to correctly install watchman.

Comment: Please read the official docs of watchman and look at how you can troubleshoot it.
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html

Comment: I actually did and there is no solution for the problem that I'm having. Thanks anyway, I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Not sure but looks like you are doing something wrong.