# Understanding react-native init template and files: What are all these files?

Tags: typescript, react-native, initialization, config

Today I started to play around with a fresh React Native project. I ran the basic react-native init command and got the sample project littered with all these weird files. Are all of these necessary and what are they?

---

`.buckconfig`

This seems to be related to a RN build tool called "Buck" made by Facebook. Is this used by default in the freshly initialise project? How can I check what builder is being used?

---

`.flowconfig`

Never heard of this before. Short googling gave me the understanding that this is some sort of type checker for JS. I am using TypeScript, so I think there's no need for this config file to be present?

---

`.watchmanconfig`

Empty watchmanconfig in the project root? Why? What's the point in having this there?

Edit: Apparently it is safe to delete from the project as long as it is not too large

[Do I need to keep .watchmanconfig file in react-native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297764/do-i-need-to-keep-watchmanconfig-file-in-react-native-project)

---

`babel.config.json`

Then probably the most confusing of them all for me was surprisingly Babel config. Babel has been present in many projects I have been working on. Always they have been some already initialised projects and I have never needed to pay much attention to the configuration details - hence this post. If using TypeScript and `tsc`, what do we need Babel for? Isn't `tsc` already transpiling the TypeScript code?

---

For a test I deleted all of the above files from my test project and it still seems to build and work just fine. I am now thinking that could this lead to some problems later in the development?

I like to keep my projects as clean as possible from all trash, so they are nicer to develop and easier to understand as there are less random stuff floating around.

Comment: The purpose of this question is to collect some answers for everyone to read and learn about the react-native initial configuration. There isn't too much explained in the official docs. Suggestions for better title are welcome and also feel free to ask about some other file that is not mentioned in the first post. I will add them into it later. Thanks

Comment: .buckconfig isn't any more a part of a default RN project at version 0.71 + so you can remove that

Answer (score 0):

**.watchmanconfig** - Used by Watchman, a file-watching service that can be used by React Native's development server to detect changes to your code and automatically reload your app. The .watchmanconfig file is used to configure how Watchman should watch your files and directories.

**babel.config.js** -Used by Babel, a JavaScript compiler that converts modern JavaScript code into an older version of JavaScript that can run on more devices. In a React Native project, Babel is used to transform your code so that it can be run on iOS and Android devices. The babel.config.js file is used to configure Babel's plugins and presets, which control how your code is transformed.

**metro.config.js** - Used by Metro, which is the JavaScript bundler used by React Native to package your code for distribution. The metro.config.js file is used to configure Metro's behavior, such as which files to include or exclude from the bundle, how to handle different types of assets, and so on.

**tsconfig.js** - Used by TypeScript is a file that used to configure the TypeScript compiler's behavior, such as which files to include or exclude from the build, how to handle different types of modules, and so on.

**.eslintrc.js** - Used by ESLint, a JavaScript linter that can be used to find and fix common errors and coding style issues in your code. The .eslintrc.js file is used to configure ESLint's rules, which control what issues it reports and how it reports them.